# Where is libcurl.a?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am trying to incorporate curl capabilities into my Win32 app using MS Visual Studio. Unfortunately, my app can't resolve several libcurl externals e.g. 'curl_easy_init'. I believe this is because I haven't included libcurl.a in my project but I haven't been able to find that library. I've downloaded the libcurl package from https://curl.se/download.html but surprisingly the 'lib' directory only contains source code. **Where is the libcurl.a binary? Am I required to build libcurl.a from source?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were on Linux, you could install the binary using the package manager provided by your distribution. You can, of course, build your own binary from the source code, but the website you mentioned also has [pre-built Windows binaries](https://curl.se/windows/) available for download.

Comment: Duh, you're right - it *is* there. I don't know how I missed it.